# Best way to match two groups of objects based on confidences

Tags: python, algorithm, charts

I searched this issue for some time but couldn't find anything relevant.

Suppose that I have two types of objects that I want to create a one-to-one correspondence between them. Let's say my first group is `integers` and my second group is `letters`. I somehow know the confidence (weight/correlation etc) of each integer, and letter pair.

Suppose also that I have 4 integers and 3 letters. Their correspondences are `1-A, 2-B, 3-C, 4-None`. (I am trying to get this result)

Also, I know the relationships between ints and letters.

```
1 -> (A, 0.9)
2 -> (B, 0.5), (C, 0.4)
3 -> (B, 0.2), (C, 0.4)
4 -> (B, 0.1)
```

The rest of them are zero, for example, `2 -> (A, 0)`, etc.

In this example, `1-A` is a pair with high confidence, `0.9`, and no other integer is matching with `A`. So, I will add this pair to the matching pairs list. Now, I need to choose between `2-B` and `2-C`, vs. `3-B` and `3-C`. Since the former one is a better option (the sum of confidences is `0.9` as opposed to `0.6`), we choose `2-B` and `2-C`.

After assigning `1, 2, 3`, to `A, B, C`, respectively, `4` will be left with nothing. So, it will be none.

I can do this using some kinda brute-force algorithm but I am looking for an elegant way to do this. To me it looks like a graph algorithm but couldn't come up with something nicer than brute force.

Is there any more elegant way that I can use for this algorithm?

Language doesn't matter at this point but I am using python.

Comment: Note: I am open to suggestions on improving the title. I don't think it is very descriptive.

Comment: If you want to maximise the sum of the confidences, you may have a look at the Hungarian algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). This [link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/assignment-problem-and-hungarian-algorithm/) explains one of the algorithms that can solve it, the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), and provides some C code that you should be able to copy and paste.

Comment: Great, it looks like that is what I was looking for. Let me dive into it further.